# Concept TLS Handshake Diffie Hellman

Tags: ssl, handshake, diffie-hellman

I try to understand the TLS Handshake with DH. I googled the concepts and I think I understood the basics. But there are somethings I'm still struggeling with.

Client and Server have to agree on the DH Params g and p. Who makes the suggestion for these parameters, always the server?

On various images I saw, that the first step is the exchange of a client random/server random. What are they used for? 
To calculate the pre-master-secret client and server only need to exchange g, p and their calculated public-value (client-public-value -> g,p and clients-Secret-Value; server-public-value -> g,p and server-secret-value. 
Why these client random and server random as a first step?

see: [Image1](https://www.google.ch/search?q=tls%20handshake%20diffie%20hellman&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjujMzKuujXAhVGK1AKHTmND3YQ_AUICigB&biw=1745&bih=899#imgrc=v5WFA7Tf6dtmkM:); [Image2](https://cdn.wp.nginx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Sullivan-conf2015-slide4_ssl-handshake.png)

What did I missunderstood?

Thank you guys

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited for security.stackexchange.com or crypto.stackexchange.com- and I'm pretty sure that there are already posts which explain DH there.

Comment: Apart from being off-topic:  the DH parameter are provided by the server. The client/server random are part of the TLS handshake, no matter if DH or RSA key exchange is used.

Comment: Thank you! Closing the question is fine.